# Python: Optimize weights in portfolio

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, optimization

I have the following dataframe with weights:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0.1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.3], 'b': [0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2], 'c': [0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1],
           'd': [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.7], 'e': [0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.4], 'f': [0.7, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]})
```

and then I normalize each row using:

```
df = df.div(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
```

I want to optimize the normalized weights of each row such that no weight is less than 0 or greater than 0.4.

If the weight is greater than 0.4, it will be clipped to 0.4 and the additional weight will be distributed to the other entries in a pro-rata fashion (meaning the second largest weight will receive more weight so it gets close to 0.4, and if there is any remaining weight, it will be distributed to the third and so on).

Can this be done using the "optimize" function?

Thank you.

UPDATE: I would also like to set a minimum bound for the weights. In my original question, the minimum weight bound was automatically considered as zero, however, I would like to set a constraint such that the minimum weight is at at least equal to 0.05, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I can only find a loop solution to this problem. When you trim off the excess weight and redistribute it proportionally, the underweight may go over the limit. Then they have to be trimmed off. And the cycle keep repeating until no value is overweight. The same goes for underweight rows.

```py
# The original data frame. No normalization yet
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": [0.1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.3],
        "b": [0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2],
        "c": [0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1],
        "d": [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.7],
        "e": [0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.4],
        "f": [0.7, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1],
    }
)


def ensure_min_weight(row: np.array, min_weight: float):
    while True:
        underweight = row < min_weight
        if not underweight.any():
            break

        missing_weight = min_weight * underweight.sum() - row[underweight].sum()
        row[~underweight] -= missing_weight / row[~underweight].sum() * row[~underweight]
        row[underweight] = min_weight


def ensure_max_weight(row: np.array, max_weight: float):
    while True:
        overweight = row > max_weight
        if not overweight.any():
            break

        excess_weight = row[overweight].sum() - (max_weight * overweight.sum())
        row[~overweight] += excess_weight / row[~overweight].sum() * row[~overweight]
        row[overweight] = max_weight


values = df.to_numpy()
normalized = values / values.sum(axis=1)[:, None]
min_weight = 0.15 # just for fun
max_weight = 0.4

for i in range(len(values)):
    row = normalized[i]
    ensure_min_weight(row, min_weight)
    ensure_max_weight(row, max_weight)

# Normalized weight
assert np.isclose(normalized.sum(axis=1), 1).all(), "Normalized weight must sum up to 1"
assert ((min_weight <= normalized) & (normalized <= max_weight)).all(), f"Normalized weight must be between {min_weight} and {max_weight}"
print(pd.DataFrame(normalized, columns=df.columns))

# Raw values
# values = normalized * values.sum(axis=1)[:, None]
# print(pd.DataFrame(values, columns=df.columns))
```

Note that this algorithm will run into infinite loop if your `min_weight` and `max_weight` are illogical: try `min_weight = 0.4` and `max_weight = 0.5`. You should handle these errors in the 2 `ensure` functions.

Comment: The solution is great, however, if you look at some of the entries in the output, they are greater than 0.4. I am not sure why that is, even though the excess weight is supposed to be trimmed due to the algorithm. Could it be that the extra weight is being redistributed to the value from which it was trimmed?

Comment: You are looking at the raw output. Normalize it and you will see no value exceeds 0.4

Comment: I have updated the question above to include an explicit minimum value for the weights. How would the code change to reflect this?

Comment: It's the same idea, just need a little modification. See my edited answer